# Не выходит из функции

Tags: c++, строки

Доброго времени суток!

В приведенном ниже коде закралась ошибка, и я не могу своими силами её разгадать.
Суть в том что не происходит не то что бы выхода из функции
а даже до "END testItow" не доходит!
При чем если написать "wcout << L"Result = " << testItow() << endl;"
что избавляет от указания типа возвращаемого значения, то все прекрасно работает.

Еще по возможности поделитесь как такие ошибки отлавливать самостоятельно,
т.к. никакие GetLastError и errno ничего не выводят т.к. вероятно программа завершается
до того как до них доходит.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <errno.h>
#include <cerrno>

using namespace std;

wchar_t* testItow();

int OffsetNumName = 33;

int main(){

    wcout << L"START" << endl;

    wchar_t* result;

    result = testItow();
    wcout << L"Result = " << result << endl;

    wcout << L"END" << endl;
    return 0;
}

// А если так то все работает:
// wcout << L"Result = " << testItow() << endl;


wchar_t* testItow(){
    wcout << L"START testItow" << endl;
    
    wchar_t* str;

    _itow(OffsetNumName, str, 16);
    
    wcout << L"END testItow" << endl;
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Используйте отладчик. Зачем гадать если можно посмотреть?

Comment: Когда я раньше кодил на ассемблере и использовал OllyDbg, Вы о нем? Если да то я уже пытался смотреть ассемблерный код скомпилированного в c++ exe файле, если честно я в ужасе был. Не думал что там столько мусора, и что бы сопоставить его с с++ кодом придется очень постараться и не один час уйдет.

Comment: Я про отладчик на уровне языка C++, где можно исполнять программу по строкам, смотреть значения переменных и т.п.

Comment: Первый раз слышу, я думал отладчики только на ассемблере бывают, где такое найти можно?

Comment: https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
wchar_t* str;
_itow(OffsetNumName, str, 16);
```

Вы планируете записать число в строку. В *какую*? Где в памяти она находится?

`str` у вас неинициализированный указатель, указывающий в неизвестно куда в памяти, вот и получается у вас UB... Который при попытке записать туда, куда писать нельзя, просто аварийно завершает программу.

Выделите место для строки (только не что-то наподобие

```
wchar_t str[20];
```

потому что это будет локальный массив, который умрет при выходе из функции, и вы просто поменяете одно неопределенное поведение на другое).

**Update**

`wstring` вас не устроит?

```
wstring testItow();

int OffsetNumName = 33;

int main(){

    wcout << L"START" << endl;

    wstring result;

    result = testItow();
    wcout << L"Result = " << result << endl;

    wcout << L"END" << endl;
    return 0;
}

// А если так то все работает:
// wcout << L"Result = " << testItow() << endl;


wstring testItow(){
    wcout << L"START testItow" << endl;

    wstring ws(20,' ');
    _itow(OffsetNumName, ws.data(), 16);
    
    wcout << L"END testItow" << endl;
    return ws;
}
```

Если с `wchar_t`, то можно так:

```
wchar_t* testItow();

int OffsetNumName = 33;

int main(){

    wcout << L"START" << endl;

    wchar_t* result;

    result = testItow();

    delete result;

    wcout << L"Result = " << result << endl;

    wcout << L"END" << endl;
    return 0;
}

// └ хёыш Єръ Єю тёх ЁрсюЄрхЄ:
// wcout << L"Result = " << testItow() << endl;


wchar_t* testItow(){
    wcout << L"START testItow" << endl;

    wchar_t* str = new wchar_t[20];

    _itow(OffsetNumName, str, 16);
    
    wcout << L"END testItow" << endl;
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Я уже об этом думал, и как раз так(wchar_t str[20]) и написал, но компилятор заругался на то что _itow требует wchar_t* а не wchar_t**.

Comment: А зачем мне не локальный, моя задача retern'ом вернуть строку и все.

Comment: И даже если это указатель низвесно куда то почему с "wcout <<  testItow() << endl" все работает?

Comment: Вы вернете указатель на строку, *которой больше нет* — время жизни локальной переменной — до выхода из функции.

Comment: Да не работает. Если вас не сшибла машина при переходе на красный светофор, это совсем не значит, что "все работает, можно переходить на красный свет!"... Например, этот указатель может случайно указывать куда-то в разрешенную область.

Comment: Через указатели тоже что то не выходит, вероятно я в них еще плохо разбираюсь. Вся цепочка исходит из того что _itow требует wchar_t* а не wchar_t, поэтому вынужден передавать параметром в функцию указатель на wchar_t string заранее объявленную в main, допустим _itow проделал свою работу изменил string, то как я теперь должен объявить result что бы ее вывести?

Comment: Вас `wstring` не устроит? См. ответ.

Comment: Благодарю, вроде работает! Получается new позволяет объявить переменную глобально, что то типа extern'а?    А если testItow будет void, возможно через указатели все провернуть без new?

Comment: `new` не делает глобальную переменную, а обеспечивает нужное время жизни, которое не заканчивается с окончанием функции. Без `new` можно провернуть с использованием `static`-переменных, но такую переменную перезапишет следующий вызов функции.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
void testItow(wchar_t *str) {
    _itow(OffsetNumName, str, 16);
}

wchar_t str[20];
testItow(str);
```

Можно так:

```
struct Str {
    wchar_t str[20];
};

Str testItow() {
    Str str;
    _itow(OffsetNumName, str.str, 16);
    return str;
}

Str str = testItow(str);
```

Можно так:

```
wchar_t *testItow() {
    wchar_t *str = malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 20);
    _itow(OffsetNumName, str, 16);
    return str;
}

wchar_t *str = testItow();
...
free(str);
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.